# Quote generator with images and text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple quote generator With the specific image and the text, When I try to run this it is not showing me any image or any text as the output it just displays `undefined`, Where am I going wrong? Here is my code:

```js
function quote() {
  var items = [
    { img: "http://quotes.values.com/quote_artwork/5909/original/20170321_tuesday_quote.jpg?1489784779",
     text: 
     "It is the province of knowledge to speak and it is the privilege of wisdom to listen. -Oliver Wendell Holmes, Sr."
    },    
    { img: "http://quotes.values.com/quote_artwork/7412/original/20151105_thursday_quote.jpg?1446154661",
     text:"Let me not pray to be sheltered from dangers, but to be fearless in facing them.Let me not beg for the stilling of my pain, but for the heart to conquer it.-Rabindranath Tagore"
    },
    { img:"http://quotes.values.com/quote_artwork/7473/original/20160126_wednesday_quote.jpg?1453410934",
     text:"The purpose of life is to live it, to taste experience to the utmost, to reach out eagerly and without fear for newer and richer experience.-Eleanor Roosevelt"},
    { img:"http://quotes.values.com/quote_artwork/7439/original/20151214_monday_quote.jpg?1449869454",
     text :"At the touch of love everyone becomes a poet. -Plato "}
    
  ];

  var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =         
  '<p>' + quote.text + '</p>' +
        '<img src="' + quote.img + '">';
  
}
```

```css
#gen {
  outline: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.6;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: thin solid white;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
#gen:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: thin solid black;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
   <div class="page-header">
     <p><h1>Simple Quote Generator </h1></p>
   </div>

  
 <div class="">
   <button id="gen" onclick="quote()" type="button" class="button-0">New Quote</button> 
      <div style="padding: 10px"></div>
   <div class="">
     <div class="panel-body" id="demo"></div>     
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing the variable `quote`, but you assigned the radom quote to the variable `item`.

Changing `quote.text` to `item.text` fixes it

```js
function quote() {
  var items = [
    { img: "http://quotes.values.com/quote_artwork/5909/original/20170321_tuesday_quote.jpg?1489784779",
     text: 
     "It is the province of knowledge to speak and it is the privilege of wisdom to listen. -Oliver Wendell Holmes, Sr."
    },    
    { img: "http://quotes.values.com/quote_artwork/7412/original/20151105_thursday_quote.jpg?1446154661",
     text:"Let me not pray to be sheltered from dangers, but to be fearless in facing them.Let me not beg for the stilling of my pain, but for the heart to conquer it.-Rabindranath Tagore"
    },
    { img:"http://quotes.values.com/quote_artwork/7473/original/20160126_wednesday_quote.jpg?1453410934",
     text:"The purpose of life is to live it, to taste experience to the utmost, to reach out eagerly and without fear for newer and richer experience.-Eleanor Roosevelt"},
    { img:"http://quotes.values.com/quote_artwork/7439/original/20151214_monday_quote.jpg?1449869454",
     text :"At the touch of love everyone becomes a poet. -Plato "}
    
  ];

  var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =         
  '<p>' + item.text + '</p>' +
        '<img src="' + item.img + '">';
  
}
```

```css
#gen {
  outline: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.6;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: thin solid white;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
#gen:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: thin solid black;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
   <div class="page-header">
     <p><h1>Simple Quote Generator </h1></p>
   </div>

  
 <div class="">
   <button id="gen" onclick="quote()" type="button" class="button-0">New Quote</button> 
      <div style="padding: 10px"></div>
   <div class="">
     <div class="panel-body" id="demo"></div>     
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`quote.text` and `quote.img` should be `item.text` and `item.img`. `item` contains the random object from your items array, whereas `quote` is the function that you are running.

```js
function quote() {
  var items = [
    { img: "http://quotes.values.com/quote_artwork/5909/original/20170321_tuesday_quote.jpg?1489784779",
     text: 
     "It is the province of knowledge to speak and it is the privilege of wisdom to listen. -Oliver Wendell Holmes, Sr."
    },    
    { img: "http://quotes.values.com/quote_artwork/7412/original/20151105_thursday_quote.jpg?1446154661",
     text:"Let me not pray to be sheltered from dangers, but to be fearless in facing them.Let me not beg for the stilling of my pain, but for the heart to conquer it.-Rabindranath Tagore"
    },
    { img:"http://quotes.values.com/quote_artwork/7473/original/20160126_wednesday_quote.jpg?1453410934",
     text:"The purpose of life is to live it, to taste experience to the utmost, to reach out eagerly and without fear for newer and richer experience.-Eleanor Roosevelt"},
    { img:"http://quotes.values.com/quote_artwork/7439/original/20151214_monday_quote.jpg?1449869454",
     text :"At the touch of love everyone becomes a poet. -Plato "}
    
  ];

  var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =         
  '<p>' + item.text + '</p>' +
        '<img src="' + item.img + '">';
  
}
```

```css
#gen {
  outline: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.6;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: thin solid white;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
#gen:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: thin solid black;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
   <div class="page-header">
     <p><h1>Simple Quote Generator </h1></p>
   </div>

  
 <div class="">
   <button id="gen" onclick="quote()" type="button" class="button-0">New Quote</button> 
      <div style="padding: 10px"></div>
   <div class="">
     <div class="panel-body" id="demo"></div>     
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function quote() {
  var items = [
    { img: "unsplash.it/1080/1080/?random",
     text: 
     "It is the province of knowledge to speak and it is the privilege of wisdom to listen. -Oliver Wendell Holmes, Sr."
    },    
    { img: "unsplash.it/1080/1080/?random",
     text:"Let me not pray to be sheltered from dangers, but to be fearless in facing them.Let me not beg for the stilling of my pain, but for the heart to conquer it.-Rabindranath Tagore"
    },
    { img:"unsplash.it/1080/1080/?random",
     text:"The purpose of life is to live it, to taste experience to the utmost, to reach out eagerly and without fear for newer and richer experience.-Eleanor Roosevelt"},
    { img:"unsplash.it/1080/1080/?random",
     text :"At the touch of love everyone becomes a poet. -Plato "}
    
  ];

  var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =         
  '<p>' + item.text + '</p>' +
        '<img src="' + item.img + '">';
  
}
```

```css
#gen {
  outline: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.6;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: thin solid white;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
#gen:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: thin solid black;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
   <div class="page-header">
     <p><h1>Simple Quote Generator </h1></p>
   </div>

  
 <div class="">
   <button id="gen" onclick="quote()" type="button" class="button-0">New Quote</button> 
      <div style="padding: 10px"></div>
   <div class="">
     <div class="panel-body" id="demo"></div>     
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please dont just provide code, explain what was the issue with previous code and how you have fixed it with yours.